# Change the className of tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a list of projects, and I want the user to select one of them to be the default project (to use it later with other processes).

My problem is, I have a list of projects and each one has a unique id and set the default class is `RegularIcon`, as follows:

```
<span :id="project.id" class="RegularIcon" @click="changeIcon(project.id, projectKey)"></span>
```

`projectKey` is the index of the current project in the list.

My function as following:

```
changeIcon: function(projectId, projectIndex) {

  let ClassName = document.getElementById(projectId).className;

  if ( ClassName == 'RegularIcon' )
  { 

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SolidIcon");
    var i;

    if ( x.length != 0 ) 
    {
      for ( i=0; i < this.ProjectsList.length; i++ )
      {
        if ( i != projectIndex ) 
        { 
          x[i].className = 'RegularIcon'; 
        }
        else {
          x[i].className = 'SolidIcon'; 
        }
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      document.getElementById(projectId).className = 'SolidIcon'; 
    }

  }
  else 
  { 
    document.getElementById(projectId).className = 'RegularIcon'; 
  }

},
```

My idea was when the user clicks on the icon (default it not filled) then after clicking on it will be solid and filled and at the same time, all other projects icons will be (not filled - regular).

But I'm got an error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'classList' of undefined
```

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate the data directly. Can't you add extra data and manipulate it instead, then mirror the changes using the Vue template?

Comment: take advantage of using vue.js and use clas binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of DOM manipulation, you could use [Vue's class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) to set a specific class based on a condition:

```
<span :class="{ CLASS1: CONDITION1, CLASS2: CONDITION2, ... }">
```

In your case, the binding would be:

```
<span :class="{ RegularIcon: CONDITION, SolidIcon: !CONDITION }">
```

...where `CONDITION` is based on user selection (e.g., the index of the selection). For instance, `RegularIcon` could be active when the icon's index does not match the selected index; and `SolidIcon` could be active when the index matches.

```
<div v-for="(project, i) in projects">
  <span :class="{ RegularIcon: i !== selectedIndex, SolidIcon: i === selectedIndex }"
        @click="selectedIndex = i"></span>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    selectedIndex: -1,
    projects: [
      {id: 1},
      {id: 2},
      {id: 3},
    ]
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(project, i) in projects" :key="project.id">
    <span class="fa-ghost"
          :class="{far: i !== selectedIndex, fas: i === selectedIndex}"
          @click="selectedIndex = i"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to click on the same icon to return it as regular when it solid. e.g. the second icon is solid when I click on it I want to change it to regular.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
document.getElementById(projectId).classList.add("classToAdd");
document.getElementById(projectId).classList.remove("classToRemove");
```